# How to import JSON to Cosmos DB

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an existing CouchDB instance with several databases.  Using Postman, I exported 10 documents to a .json file.  Using DocumentDB Data Migration Tool I was able to import the contents of this file to Cosmos.

However, it seems I have effectively imported a single document. Azure Data Explorer indicates I have one single document in my "collection".

In CouchDB, the highest-level Identifier is doc._id.  I have tried specifying "doc._id", "id", and "_id" as my ID Field, all to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?  How do I import each JSON document separately?

---

Sample document:

```
{
    "_id": "3147cb0e74449e1c28c6ded2b4a3fa45e0d65481-bd_RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com_2017-11-30T13:38:33.955Z", 
    "_rev": "3-99aef1458fe1a8f310c83156b9d06a69", 
    "delivery": {
        "application": "EnvTest", 
        "sender": {
            "id": "RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com", 
            "type": "user"
        }, 
        "recipients": [
            {
                "type": "email", 
                "recipient": "\"Artzer, Daniel J\" <DJArtzer@emailaddress.com>", 
                "sentTS": "2018-01-30T19:46:31.515Z", 
                "id": "45281ab0-05f6-11e8-a86a-61a54dcb42aa"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "payload": {
        "startTS": "2017-11-30T07:38:33-06:00", 
        "equipmentOrLineType": "gathering system", 
        "scheduledIndicator": "upset", 
        "field": "Gulf Plains", 
        "eventDateTime": "2017-11-30T07:31:39-06:00", 
        "numCopies": "1", 
        "region": "South", 
        "facility": "", 
        "equipment": "", 
        "causeForRelease": "", 
        "correctiveAction": "", 
        "hgbUsed": "no-hgb-available", 
        "esdActivated": "no", 
        "submitTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:33.940Z", 
        "lineSegment": [
            {
                "lineName": "GPL-1", 
                "Diameter": "12.725", 
                "Length": "1000", 
                "duration": "no", 
                "volume": "3"
            }
        ], 
        "creator": "RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com", 
        "savedTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:33.955Z", 
        "trainingDoc": true, 
        "_id": "bd_RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com_2017-11-30T13:38:33.955Z", 
        "syncTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:34.794Z"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used DocumentDB Data Migration Tool to import one .json file which contains 4 documents and it works well for me.

My `.json` file :

```
[
    {
        "name":"jay1",
        "age":20
    },
    {
        "name":"jay2",
        "age":20
    },
    {
        "name":"jay3",
        "age":20
    },
    {
        "name":"jay4",
        "age":20
    }
]
```

And the documents are imported into collection separately.

[image]

> The JSON file source importer option allows you to import one or more
>   single document JSON files or JSON files that each contain an array of
>   JSON documents. When adding folders that contain JSON files to import,
>   you have the option of recursively searching for files in subfolders.

You could check if you followed the above rules which is stated in the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data) to create your .json file. (For example , are your documents in an array?)

Hope it helps you.

---

***Update Answer:***

I tired to import data which is followed the format you mentioned in the reply into cosmos db.

My update `.json` file:

```
[
    {
        "id":"001",
        "name":"jay1",
        "age":20,
        "array": {
            "a":1,
            "b":2,
            "c":{
                "d":3,
                "e": {
                    "f":4
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id":"002",
        "name":"jay2",
        "age":20,
        "array": {
            "a":1,
            "b":2,
            "c":{
                "d":3,
                "e": {
                    "f":4
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id":"003",
        "name":"jay3",
        "age":20,
        "array": {
            "a":1,
            "b":2,
            "c":{
                "d":3,
                "e": {
                    "f":4
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And the documents are imported into collection successfully.

[image]

---

***Update Answer 2:***

I followed the format of the document you offered and created 3 sample documents in my .json file.(I just update the '_id' property to 'testX')

My `.json` file:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "test1", 
        "_rev": "3-99aef1458fe1a8f310c83156b9d06a69", 
        "delivery": {
            "application": "EnvTest", 
            "sender": {
                "id": "RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com", 
                "type": "user"
            }, 
            "recipients": [
                {
                    "type": "email", 
                    "recipient": "\"Artzer, Daniel J\" <DJArtzer@emailaddress.com>", 
                    "sentTS": "2018-01-30T19:46:31.515Z", 
                    "id": "45281ab0-05f6-11e8-a86a-61a54dcb42aa"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "payload": {
            "startTS": "2017-11-30T07:38:33-06:00", 
            "equipmentOrLineType": "gathering system", 
            "scheduledIndicator": "upset", 
            "field": "Gulf Plains", 
            "eventDateTime": "2017-11-30T07:31:39-06:00", 
            "numCopies": "1", 
            "region": "South", 
            "facility": "", 
            "equipment": "", 
            "causeForRelease": "", 
            "correctiveAction": "", 
            "hgbUsed": "no-hgb-available", 
            "esdActivated": "no", 
            "submitTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:33.940Z", 
            "lineSegment": [
                {
                    "lineName": "GPL-1", 
                    "Diameter": "12.725", 
                    "Length": "1000", 
                    "duration": "no", 
                    "volume": "3"
                }
            ], 
            "creator": "RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com", 
            "savedTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:33.955Z", 
            "trainingDoc": true, 
            "_id": "bd_RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com_2017-11-30T13:38:33.955Z", 
            "syncTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:34.794Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "test2", 
        "_rev": "3-99aef1458fe1a8f310c83156b9d06a69", 
        "delivery": {
            "application": "EnvTest", 
            "sender": {
                "id": "RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com", 
                "type": "user"
            }, 
            "recipients": [
                {
                    "type": "email", 
                    "recipient": "\"Artzer, Daniel J\" <DJArtzer@emailaddress.com>", 
                    "sentTS": "2018-01-30T19:46:31.515Z", 
                    "id": "45281ab0-05f6-11e8-a86a-61a54dcb42aa"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "payload": {
            "startTS": "2017-11-30T07:38:33-06:00", 
            "equipmentOrLineType": "gathering system", 
            "scheduledIndicator": "upset", 
            "field": "Gulf Plains", 
            "eventDateTime": "2017-11-30T07:31:39-06:00", 
            "numCopies": "1", 
            "region": "South", 
            "facility": "", 
            "equipment": "", 
            "causeForRelease": "", 
            "correctiveAction": "", 
            "hgbUsed": "no-hgb-available", 
            "esdActivated": "no", 
            "submitTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:33.940Z", 
            "lineSegment": [
                {
                    "lineName": "GPL-1", 
                    "Diameter": "12.725", 
                    "Length": "1000", 
                    "duration": "no", 
                    "volume": "3"
                }
            ], 
            "creator": "RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com", 
            "savedTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:33.955Z", 
            "trainingDoc": true, 
            "_id": "bd_RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com_2017-11-30T13:38:33.955Z", 
            "syncTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:34.794Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "test3", 
        "_rev": "3-99aef1458fe1a8f310c83156b9d06a69", 
        "delivery": {
            "application": "EnvTest", 
            "sender": {
                "id": "RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com", 
                "type": "user"
            }, 
            "recipients": [
                {
                    "type": "email", 
                    "recipient": "\"Artzer, Daniel J\" <DJArtzer@emailaddress.com>", 
                    "sentTS": "2018-01-30T19:46:31.515Z", 
                    "id": "45281ab0-05f6-11e8-a86a-61a54dcb42aa"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "payload": {
            "startTS": "2017-11-30T07:38:33-06:00", 
            "equipmentOrLineType": "gathering system", 
            "scheduledIndicator": "upset", 
            "field": "Gulf Plains", 
            "eventDateTime": "2017-11-30T07:31:39-06:00", 
            "numCopies": "1", 
            "region": "South", 
            "facility": "", 
            "equipment": "", 
            "causeForRelease": "", 
            "correctiveAction": "", 
            "hgbUsed": "no-hgb-available", 
            "esdActivated": "no", 
            "submitTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:33.940Z", 
            "lineSegment": [
                {
                    "lineName": "GPL-1", 
                    "Diameter": "12.725", 
                    "Length": "1000", 
                    "duration": "no", 
                    "volume": "3"
                }
            ], 
            "creator": "RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com", 
            "savedTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:33.955Z", 
            "trainingDoc": true, 
            "_id": "bd_RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com_2017-11-30T13:38:33.955Z", 
            "syncTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:34.794Z"
        }
    }
]
```

The documents were imported into the db and no error occurred.

[image]

If any differences between you and me ,please let me know.

Comment: thank you.  Perhaps my problem is my JSON document is more complex than is permitted.  I saved a file of multiple JSON documents, each of which contain 3 nested Objects.  Perhaps this format is not compatible in some way?  I can provide a sample if that would be helpful.

Comment: @CarCrazyBen That will be helpful if you offer a sample document you want to import .I'll test on my side via the tool.

Comment: here is a sample document.  This may be a mess because I have to send it in 2 parts:
{ "_id": "3147cb0e74449e1c28c6ded2b4a3fa45e0d65481-bd_RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com_2017-11-30T13:38:33.955Z",
  "_rev": "3-99aef1458fe1a8f310c83156b9d06a69",
  "delivery": {
   "application": "EnvTest",
   "sender": {"id": "RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com","type": "user"},
   "recipients":
   [
    {"type": "email","recipient": "\"Artzer, Daniel J\" <DJArtzer@emailaddress.com>", "sentTS": "2018-01-30T19:46:31.515Z","id": "45281ab0-05f6-11e8-a86a-61a54dcb42aa"},
   ]
  },

Comment: "payload": {
   "startTS": "2017-11-30T07:38:33-06:00",
   "equipmentOrLineType": "gathering system",
   "scheduledIndicator": "upset",
   "field": "Gulf Plains",
   "eventDateTime": "2017-11-30T07:31:39-06:00",
   "numCopies": "1",
   "region": "South",
   "facility": "",
   "equipment": "",
   "causeForRelease": "",
   "correctiveAction": "",
   "hgbUsed": "no-hgb-available",
   "esdActivated": "no",
   "submitTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:33.940Z",

Comment: "lineSegment": [
    {"lineName": "GPL-1",
     "Diameter": "12.725",
     "Length": "1000",
     "duration": "no",
     "volume": "3"}
   ],
   "creator": "RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com",
   "savedTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:33.955Z",
   "trainingDoc": true,
   "_id": "bd_RXMARTINEZ@emailaddress.com_2017-11-30T13:38:33.955Z",
   "syncTS": "2017-11-30T13:38:34.794Z"
  }
}

Correction, 3 parts.

Comment: please see sample document I provided in Comments.  Thank you for your help with this!

Comment: @CarCrazyBen Well, I will  try to put the pieces together. In fact, you could post the sample document in your question instead in the comment,it'll be more clear.

Comment: @CarCrazyBen Hi, please see my update answer 2.If any concern,just let me know. BTW, I already added your sample document in your question for you,it will be more clear.

Comment: I think I see the difference now.  You enclosed the documents list in square brackets, [], while I did not.  I will re-try the Data Migration Tool.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @CarCrazyBen Yes, you need to put multiple documents into an array [] if you want to import them.That's the key! If you done successfully, you could mark this answer for others' reference on the forum. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is about a year ago, it uses `dtui.exe`.

`dtui.exe` is a GUI tool
`dt.exe` is a command-line tool

Both can be downloaded as of today from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46436

Below solution uses **`dt.exe`** (automates your process so that it can be repeated & without issues in future too)

```
`"C:\path-to-your-dt-exe\dt.exe"  /s:JsonFile   /s.Files:"C:\path-to-your-json-files-of-one-collection-only\*.json"   /t:DocumentDB    /t.ConnectionString:"AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=<big account key here>;Database=<your db name here>"   /t.Collection:<your collection name here>   /t.PartitionKey:<your partition key here>   /t.CollectionThroughput:2500`
```

**Note**
- database (`<your db name here>`) & collection (`<your collection name here>`) in above, must already exist
- replace `<...>` with your data in above, and run in `cmd`.
- `/s` is the source, `/t` is the target, here the source is `JSON` files, and the target is local `documentBD`

Hope that helps.